# How to type hint a return value that's defined in the function's local scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory, type-hinting, typing

Given the following example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, num: int):
        self.num = num

    def bar(self, eggs: int):
        if eggs == self.num:
            raise ValueError


def foo(spam: bool) -> B:
    class B(A):
        def bar(self, eggs: int):
            try:
                super().bar(eggs)
            except ValueError as e:
                if not spam:
                    raise e
    return B
```

The base class `A` has a method named `bar` that raises a `ValueError` if `eggs` equals to `self.num`. I also have a function named `foo` that accepts an argument `spam`, it returns a subclass of `A` and overrides the `bar` method so that no `ValueError` will be raised if `spam` is non Falsey.

I'm trying to type hint the return value for the `foo` function. If I do `-> B`, `B` is undefined. If I do `-> A`, type `B` isn't exactly `A`. If I do `-> "B"`, using future hinting, `B` is still not defined since it's in a local scope.

Is there anyway to type hint this? If not, is there a better way to rewrite my code?

Comment: Neither `bar` function has a `self` argument. Shouldn't you declare them `@classmethod`s?

Comment: @DyZ My mistake. It's just an example and I forgot to add it, I will now add a `self` argument.

Comment: Show an example of how do you want to use function `foo`

Comment: @Waket There is another module/function that takes in a class constructor as an argument with the default being `A`. The argument class should be a subclass of `A`. I would like to dynamically create subclasses of `A` with dynamic traits (`spam`) when overriding the method `bar`. Anyways, I don't think the above information is necessary to answer my question since I'm solely trying to find out how you would type hint the return value of `foo`. But I guess it wouldn't hurt to add more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I could think of from a quick scan of the docs. This isn't a good solution at all (I think), but it should do the job for you.

There's something called `typing.TypeVar` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)). Its basically a generic type. So what you could possibly do is:

At the global level (after defining class A) define:

```
from typing import TypeVar
B = TypeVar('B', bound=A)
```

Now in the function signature of `def foo` you can say:

```
def foo(spam: bool) -> B:
```

Then inside the function you can continue to create a new class with the name B and return it.

I'm not even sure if this would work properly in all cases. If you find any problems with it, definitely correct me and post here.

Comment: I downvote, because lone type variable (not bound in signature arguments) makes zero sense as a return type and shouldn't be used this way. `mypy` will even emit an error for such type variable. Only using `-> A` is a correct solution, and it is fully correct (since `A` and `B` are equivalent from typing perspective).