# How to annotate return type for a Python function returning a class defined within that function?

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

Suppose I have a decorator defined using a callable class as a wrapper. For example:

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, cast

def decorator(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs

        def __call__(self, func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper

    return Wrapper()
```

How to properly annotate type its return type?

So far, I found that the following inheritance "trick" works as I expect:

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, cast

class BaseWrapper:
    def __call__(self, func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper


def decorator(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> BaseWrapper:
    class Wrapper(BaseWrapper):
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs

    return Wrapper()
```

But is there any other way? I just don't want to have the `BaseWrapper` in the module's namespace.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint a return value that's defined in the function's local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867675/how-to-type-hint-a-return-value-thats-defined-in-the-functions-local-scope)

Comment: *I just don't want to have the BaseWrapper in the module's namespace.* - just `del` it after usage?

Comment: @Ftagliacarne - to make it clear. It looks, like there's no other way. Isn't it? The solution to the post you refer is downvoted... I am not sure whether to follow it...

Comment: @STerliakov - Nice idea, but raising `NameError`.

Comment: Ough, sorry, didn't get my morning coffee before suggesting that... I'd probably make a `_wrappers.py` module and import it, referring to `BaseWrapper` as `_wrappers.BaseWrapper`. You won't have `BaseWrapper` in namespace after that. Also you can just call it `_BaseWrapper` and stop on it - underscore prefix is always "don't use me unless you know for sure what's going on".

Comment: In more complicated cases it may be beneficial to make `BaseWrapper` a public `Procotol` or `abc.ABC` to allow referring to it in type hints by other users too.